# Spring boot get request parameter

Tags: spring-boot

I have the following controller

```
@GetMapping(value = { "/live-search" })
public String liveSearch(Model model, @PathVariable("term") String term) {
    System.out.println("CALLED!");

    return "search";
}
```

But when I go the following URL

http://localhost:8080/live-search?term=test

I get

```
Missing URI template variable 'term' for method parameter of type String]
```

I have `term` set as my path variable, why am I still getting an exception about missing 'term'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are after `@RequestParam`.

---

`@PathVariable` would be like this

```
@GetMapping("/live-search/{term}")
public String liveSearch(Model model, @PathVariable("term") String term) {
    System.out.println(term);

    return "search";
}
```

Then call `../live-search/CALLED`

---

If you do wish to pass the data as a `GET`, it would be like this:

```
@GetMapping("/live-search")
public String liveSearch(Model model, @RequestParam("term") String term) {
    System.out.println(term);

    return "search";
}
```

Then call `../live-serach?term=CALLED`

Comment: I'm using your second example, and now when I go to `http://localhost:8080/live-search?term=test` I get 404

Comment: is your SysOut printing?
have you got a `search` page to return?

Comment: The sysout is not printing

Comment: My bad, had the wrong `@GetMapping` should be `@GetMapping("/live-search")`

Comment: now it gives the same error again `Missing request attribute 'term' of type String`

Comment: My memory failed me, it wasn't `@RequestAttribute` it was `@RequestParam` , updated answer as well